# Installing cqual on Ubuntu says linux/config.h not found

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install cqual-0.991 tool on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I downloaded the tar file. Ensured emacs is installed which is a per-requisite for cqual. Then, ran the command

```
    ./configure
    make
```

But I get the below error message:

```
    In file included from regions.c:40:0:
    stats.c:52:26: fatal error: linux/config.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make[3]: *** [regions.o] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/romaan/Desktop/SATool/cqual-0.991/src/libcompat'
    make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/romaan/Desktop/SATool/cqual-0.991/src'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/romaan/Desktop/SATool/cqual-0.991/src'
    make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    root@ubuntu:/home/romaan/Desktop/SATool/cqual-0.991# su -
    root@ubuntu:~# cd /home/romaan/Desktop/SATool/cqual-0.991/
    root@ubuntu:/home/romaan/Desktop/SATool/cqual-0.991# make
    Making all in src
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/romaan/Desktop/SATool/cqual-0.991/src'
    make  all-recursive
    make[2]: Entering directory `/home/romaan/Desktop/SATool/cqual-0.991/src'
    Making all in libcompat
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/romaan/Desktop/SATool/cqual-0.991/src/libcompat'
    if gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\"         -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"cqual\" -DVERSION=\"0.991\" -DYYTEXT_POINTER=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_FCNTL_H=1 -DHAVE_LIMITS_H=1 -DHAVE_MALLOC_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DTIME_WITH_SYS_TIME=1 -DSIZEOF_VOIDP=4 -DHAVE_ALLOCA_H=1 -DHAVE_ALLOCA=1 -DPROTOTYPES=1 -D__PROTOTYPES=1 -DRETSIGTYPE=void -DHAVE_VPRINTF=1 -DHAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY=1 -DHAVE_STRDUP=1 -DHAVE_STRTOLD=1 -DHAVE_STRTOL=1  -I. -I. -DNMEMDEBUG -DNDEBUG -O9    -g -O2 -MT regions.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/regions.Tpo" \
  -c -o regions.o `test -f 'regions.c' || echo './'`regions.c; \
then mv -f ".deps/regions.Tpo" ".deps/regions.Po"; \
else rm -f ".deps/regions.Tpo"; exit 1; \
fi
    In file included from regions.c:40:0:
    stats.c:52:26: fatal error: linux/config.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make[3]: *** [regions.o] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/romaan/Desktop/SATool/cqual-0.991/src/libcompat'
    make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/romaan/Desktop/SATool/cqual-0.991/src'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/romaan/Desktop/SATool/cqual-0.991/src'
    make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Do you have the `linux-headers-generic` package installed?

Comment: I have "linux-headers-3.2.0-26" but I checked for config.h . But could not find. I used the command: find / -name "config.h" -print | grep linux

Comment: `cqual-0.991` is from **2004**. I don't think you are going to be able to compile it in a modern Linux distribution. I tried compiling the latest trunk from SVN and that also is so old (2006) that it fails when `bison` is trying to parse its input files.

Comment: Thanks Romano, I suspected I could not install on new linux distros... So is there any way I will be able to compile this on any other environments available today??? Thanks a lot Romano....

Comment: If it is viable I would suggest installing an older distribution in a VM, trying to compile it there and then see if you can run the binaries on a more modern distribution. I also had a quick look at [oink](https://daniel-wilkerson.appspot.com/oink/index.html) but I couldn't compile it either, and development also seems to have stagnated in recent times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CQual is now obsolete and cannot be installed on new version of Linux or Solaris. :(

Comment: I'd think there "should" be a way to get cqual[++] running on Ubuntu; it's not obsolete, it's pretty important. David Wheeler mentions in his superb essay on the Heartbleed bug [1]: "The only static analysis tool I've found so far that existed at the time, and was able to find Heartbleed ahead-of-time without a non-standard or specialized configuration, is the FLOSS tool CQual++ ..." 

And Heartbleed was publicly announced (and fixed) on 07 Apr 2014. (The 'correct' ans above is dated 30 Oct '12 and says it's obsolete).
[1] https://www.dwheeler.com/essays/heartbleed.html